# Working with Dreamweaver and ASP.NET - is this recommended?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, dreamweaver

I am a ASP.NET 3.5 web developer using VS 2008. I just started at a new company and there are alot of Web Designers here (never worked with Web Designers before). They all use Dreamweaver CS3 and PhotoShop (something i know nothing about).

**What I would like to know is the following:**

- Would they have problems opening my ASP.NET pages in Dreamweaver? ( I heard they might not be able to ).
- What about when i use MasterPages? Will they be able to open my pages when i use MasterPages, or must i stay away from MasterPages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

They will be able to work with the markup in your aspx pages, as long as you aern't using complex server controls. Keep the markup fairly simple and you'll be OK. With master pages, they should be able to handle the layout stuff they need, and leave you to worry about the content areas. If you have the opportunity, try to go down a MVC route, this way you are encouraged to keep the code and the markup separate, and the designers will have an easy time seeing your aspx and ascx markup. Designers aren't evil, just different :)

Comment: Thanks Steve. Etienne, it is a different way of doing asp.net which might help you to make pages that your designers can work with without tripping over your code. It may not be right for you or your team, but it is a good skillset to acquire if you get chance, and there's plenty of help at the address that Steve posted. Happy coding :)